# canot load js:function with variable

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii1.x

I use the extension EFullcalendarheart , by making after click event will pop up. but fuction does not load into the intended controller.

--controller

```
 public function actionView2($id)
        {

            $this->renderPartial('view2',
                array('model'=>$this->loadModel($id)),false,true
            );
        }
```

--view

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.fullcalendar.EFullCalendarHeart', array(
//  'themeCssFile'=>'cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css',
    'options'=>array(
        'header'=>array(
            'left'=>'prev,today,next',
            'center'=>'title',
            'right'=>'month',
                    //'right'=>',agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        ),
        'events'=> $this->createUrl('peminjaman/calendarevents'),
        'eventClick'=> 'js:function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $("#myModalHeader").html(calEvent.title);
            $("#myModalBody").load("'.Yii::app()->createUrl("peminjaman/view2/id/").'"+calEvent.id);
            $("#myModal").modal();
                }',
    )));
?>

<?php $this->beginWidget(
    'booster.widgets.TbModal',
    array('id' => 'myModal')
); ?>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h4 id="myModalHeader"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
        <p>----</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php $this->widget(
            'booster.widgets.TbButton',
            array(
                'label' => 'Close',
                'url' => '#',
                'htmlOptions' => array('data-dismiss' => 'modal'),
            )
        ); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

how to solve it, to make a pop up view event or input details for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you missed the echo.
try
<?php echo $this->widget('ext.fullcalendar.EFullCalendarHeart', array());

Comment: If using echo there will be an error: Object of class EFullCalendarHeart could not be converted to string.

Comment: I tried to do the command to access the controller Yii-> app () -> createUrl (/peminjaman/ view2 / id /) + calEvent.id. but the results obtained /peminjaman/view2/en.html17 are not as expected /peminjaman/view2/id/17.html `$("#myModalBody").load("'.Yii::app()->createUrl("peminjaman/view2/id/").'"+calEvent.id);`